# RoR & ACTS_AS_Tree & display show page from database vs. display content

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-plugins, acts-as-tree

All,

Working on a RoR app for work.  Finally got acts as tree working with a database connection (railscast.com episode 162).  Trying to shift from displaying content in the database to redirecting to the contents of the page.content database entry -- any ideas?  I've tried simply replacing the display action with redirect_to, no dice.  Googling all over the place - out of time - help..

My flow is as follows:

```
pages.rb:  acts_as_tree command
application.html.erb: menu display for root entries
pages/show.html.erb:
```

- displays submenu, no problem
 - display breadcrumbs, no problem
 - display page name, no problem (envision removing this once redirect works)
 - display contents of page.content:
    <%= simple_format @page.content %>
    no problem

Problem is I want to redirect to the contents of @page.content and not display it.  Or I can shift to a different controller action, but the idea is that I need to be able to use the navigation menu to move around to different pages (that alrady exist) vs just showing the content.  Ideas?

Thanks,
Adam

Comment: Are you saying that `@page.contents` is a link that you can redirect to?